# Dropbox to new Hard Drive Migration Safety

Tags: windows, windows-10, dropbox

I have a dropbox folder with about of TB worth of info. I am migrating it to a new drive.

I didn't want to use the Dropbox "Move" function, as I've tried it before and it feels really buggy and slow compared to normal copy file operations.

I manually copied the dropbox folder to the new computer. Am I saw to just switch my dropbox location to the new folder? Will it auto recognize that all the same files are in there? I just want to avoid it seeing all the files are new/modified and attempting to upload it. Also want to make sure NO data gets corrupted, obviously.

I'm using Windows 10 if that makes a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have copied your files while conserving time-stamps and all other
attributes, Dropbox is supposed to compare them to what you have in your
account and only sync the needed changes.

While Dropbox is re-indexing your files, this can take some time if you have
a large number of files and may give the appearance that it is syncing all
of your files, but it's just comparing them.

This is a normal process of Dropbox and cannot be avoided.

Comment: great, That's what I was hoping/figured, was just a bit afraid. I have hard  2 hard copies of my entire dropbox currently, just re-syncing that much info if something got corrupt was scaring me. sounds like we are good to switch it then, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you install Dropbox on a computer, it uses a physical folder on that computer. You can see it in Dropbox and you can open it in Windows Explorer.  So set up Dropbox, log in, set up a local folder. Close Dropbox, open the folder with Windows Explorer and copy (or move) your folders into it. That will work providing that the cloud folders are the same. If there are differences, it will sync the differences

Comment: so basically setting a new folder as the dropbox folder causes dropbox to just scan whatever folder that is and look for file changes? so switch the folder should be fine?

Comment: Yes, that should work. If / when a sync starts, it will take a while, but no big copies or moves if the files are the same

Comment: Thank you so much @John !